# Как перевести словосочетание taken off в данном контексте?

Tags: структуры-данных

> In Computer Science a queue is an abstract Data Structure where items are kept in order. New items can be added at the back of the queue and old items are taken off from the front of the queue.

Comment: почему бы вам литературу в переводе не почитать, если знаний языка не хватает для чтения на английском? Тем более по таким базовым структурам данных литературы множество. Даже если вы просто откроете описание Очереди в википедии, до там и так будет ясно, о чем идет речь. И даже без описания термина это должно быть очевидно, особенно, если вы смогли перевести остальную часть предложения.

Comment: @gsdheh Такого содержания вопрос, конечно, лучше задать в [этой](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) версии ресурса, но не вижу причины не ответить на этот вопрос тут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... существующие/старые элементы удаляются/убираются/вынимаются из начала очереди

Comment: добавляются -> удаляются, имхо будет уместнее, чем вынимаются.

Answer (score 1):

Дословный перевод:

> В информатике очередь - это абстрактная структура данных, в которой элементы хранятся в последовательности (очереди). Новые элементы могут быть добавлены в конец очереди, а старые элементы ***удалены из*** передней части очереди.

Answer (score 1):

> New items can be added at the back of the queue and old items are taken off from the front of the queue.

**Новые элементы могут быть добавлены в конец очереди, и (самые) старые элементы извлекаются из начала очереди.**

PS. Тот же яндекс-переводчик для "to take off" приоритетным вариантом даёт `снять, снимать`, и `remove` в качестве синонима.

Comment: "извлекаются" - хорошее слово, давно не использовал. "Завтра на панихиде скажу."